# how to schedule a query in Azure synapse on-demand

Tags: azure-synapse

how to schedule a Query in Azure Synapse On-demand and save the result to a azure storage every 1 hour

my idea is to materialize the results into a separate storage and use PowerBI to access the results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the fact that PowerBI can directly access your Synapse instance, if you want to go this route you have several options:

1. This can be done using a pipeline in the new Synapse Workspace. You should be aware that this technology is still in preview.
2. Use Polybase and Stored Procedures on a Job Scheduler to INSERT to a Blob Storage location. There is a lot of configuration in this option.
3. At present, I would recommend Azure Data Factory (ADF) on a Schedule Trigger. This is the simplest and most reliable of the current options. Based on the scenario you described, a single Copy activity could easily perform this task.

Comment: Yes it can. Just make sure you add it as a data source in the pipelines using the connection string of SQL on-demand that you can find in Azure Portal in essentials part. It should look like {workspace_name}-ondemand.sql.azuresynapse.net.